# ELASTICSEARCH - Get a count of values from the most recent document

Tags: elasticsearch

I can't get a count of fields with a filtered document value.

I have this json

``
{

```
"took" : 6,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "net",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "RTHRTH",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "created_at" : "2020-05-31 19:01:01",
          "data" : [...]
      {
        "_index" : "net",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "LLLoIJBHHM",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "created_at" : "2020-06-23 15:11:59",
          "data" : [...]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
``
```

In the "data" field, there are more fields within other fields respectively.

I want to filter the most recent document, and then count a certain value in the most recent document.
This is my query:

```
`{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name.keyword": "net"
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "created_at.keyword": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "size": 1,
  "aggs": {
    "CountValue": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "data.add.serv.desc.keyword",
        "include": "nginx"
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

And the output is:

```
`{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "CountValue" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "nginx",
          "doc_count" : 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }`
```

I suspect that doc_count is the number of documents the value appears in, not the number of times the value is repeated within the filtered document.
Any advice I will be very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless any of the fields under the path `data.add.serv` are of the [nested type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html), the `terms` agg will produce per-whole-doc results, not per-field.

Exempli gratia:

```
POST example/_doc
{
  "serv": [
    {
      "desc": "nginx"
    },
    {
      "desc": "nginx"
    },
    {
      "desc": "nginx"
    }
  ]
}

then 


GET example/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "serv.desc.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

produces `doc_count`==1.

When, however, specified as `nested`:

```
DELETE example

PUT example
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "serv": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST example/_doc
{"serv":[{"desc":"nginx"},{"desc":"nginx"},{"desc":"nginx"}]}

then

GET example/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "serv"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "NAME": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "serv.desc.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

we end up with `doc_count`==3.

This has to do with the way non-nested array types are flattened and de-duplicated. At the end, you may need to reindex your collections after having applied the nested mapping.

---

EDIT

In order to only take the latest doc, you could do the following:

```
PUT example
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "serv": {
        "type": "nested"
      },
      "created_at": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then

```
POST example/_doc
{
  "created_at" : "2020-05-31 19:01:01",
  "serv": [
    {
      "desc": "nginx"
    },
    {
      "desc": "nginx"
    },
    {
      "desc": "nginx"
    }
  ]
}

POST example/_doc
{
  "created_at" : "2020-06-23 15:11:59",
  "serv": [
    {
      "desc": "nginx"
    },
    {
      "desc": "nginx"
    }
  ]
}
```

then use a terms agg of size 1, sorted by timestamp desc:

```
GET example/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "created_at",
        "order": {
          "_term": "desc"
        },
        "size": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "NAME2": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "serv"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "NAME": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "serv.desc.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, 
That was the answer to the "count" problem.
I need to filter by the document with the most recent date
If you know the way without applying a range between two values, it would be very useful to me.
Anyway thank yoy so much Joe

Comment: Hello Joe, 
is it possible to get aggregation of true values ​​in boolean field?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63093724/elasticsearch-how-can-i-get-an-aggregation-in-a-boolean-field