# ELASTICSEARCH - How can i get an aggregation in a boolean field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get aggregation in a boolean field, but the out is a error:

query:

"""
{

```
"size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "RecentCreated": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "created_at.keyword",
        "order": {
          "_key": "desc"
        },
        "size": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nestedData": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "data.add.serv"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "NAME": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "data.add.serv.beast"
                , "include": true
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

"""

error:

"type" : "x_content_parse_exception",
"reason" : "[terms] include doesn't support values of type: VALUE_BOOLEAN"

I have been reading that it is possible to transform the true values ​​into 1 through script to get count in the aggregation, but I cannot get the result of the true values
How could I get a count of the boolean field with true value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you might want to do is use a [filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) aggregation over your nested document rather than a `terms` aggregation. So in short change this bit of your query:

```
"aggs": {
  "NAME": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "data.add.serv.beast",
      "include": true
    }
  }
}
```

to

```
"aggs": {
  "NAME": {
    "filter": {
      "term": {
        "data.add.serv.beast": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not too familiar with nested aggregations, so there might still be an error with my syntax. The main point is to use a `filter` aggregation rather than `terms`,  hopefully that should work for you.